# Why do people use STFT as a preprocessing step to using CNN?

Tags: fourier-transform, stft, machine-learning

Just briefly looking up some research papers on audio data and I have come across some papers that use STFT as a preprocessing step to using CNN. Why is this the case? What are the advantages and disadvantages of doing so?

Some research papers that use STFT;

- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.02898.pdf
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6928168/

Comment: Because CNN blocks act as feature extractors. They look at STFT/mel-spectrogram and detect spectro-temporal patterns. So instead of using MFCC's, etc., you simply feed the spectrogram and let the network to infer what are meaningful features. Some advantag is of course simplicity and possibility that the network will learn complicated concepts and features that you wouldn't come up with. Example disadvantages are computational/memory load and possibility that network will learn something you don't want (channel, distortions, etc). Those can be somewhat mitigated and CNN's work OK.

Comment: @jojek ...this is an answer :)

Comment: @A_A I am a bit busy right now and just wanted to give Sam something. I might write a proper one later ;)

Comment: Thanks @jojek I appreciate your response -- would it make sense to use a STFT and a mel-spectrogram as input into a CNN? Does order matter here?